# Bitbucket-Laravel-Azure Web App: Artifacts not uploaded

Tags: bitbucket-pipelines

Artifacts is not uploaded after successful test pipeline. What's wrong with the code below?

[image]

Here's the result:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please do not upload images with source code, write a code bock instead.

Answer (score 2):

You are using a variable in your artefact name, which is currently [not supported](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/Variable-substitution-in-script-and-artifacts-sections/qaq-p/1685997). As `artifacts` section is a separate post-script behaviour, your `Test` step is perfectly green.

To solve the issue, use a constant name for your artefact. Alternatively, you can combine the packaging and deployment steps into a single one:

```yaml
script:
 - echo "Packaging and deploying to test environment"
 - zip -r example-$BITBUCKET_BUILD_NUMBER.zip .
 - pipe: ...
```

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I did both tried using the pipe and constant and both are working. But I need to separate the step for deployment and is there a way to pass the generated zip to artifacts dynamically - I mean not using a constant?

Comment: I also tested manually uploading the file using "- pipe: atlassian/bitbucket-upload-file:0.1.2" it has no errors but uploaded files cannot be seen on the artifact.

Comment: @esimonov +1
Thanks for the pointer! Indeed BB pipelines do no support naming a artifact directory using a variable!
Using a constant name for the path worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

This advice works https://stackoverflow.com/a/72570848/14740671  but I need to separate the deployment. I also tried uploading the file using this code:

```
            - pipe: atlassian/bitbucket-upload-file:0.3.2
              variables:
                BITBUCKET_USERNAME: $BITBUCKET_UPLOAD_USERNAME
                BITBUCKET_APP_PASSWORD: $BITBUCKET_UPLOAD_PWD
                FILENAME: "example-1.zip"
```

It has no errors but file is still no seen in the Artifacts and azure deployments has `"FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/example-1.zip'"`